# How to use the patterns and practices

Tags: development, pnp

i have been looking around for how to use sharepoint patterns and practices on the pnp site. but it seems to me so broad and overwhelming i don't know how to use it. i can see so many projects there and the documentation is not organized as a book and it is not easy to follow. how do you use it?

Answer (score 6):

You're absolutely right about documentation. IMHO, documentation is the weakest part of the PnP library. They did a lot of cool things in the library, but without good documentation is extremely hard to start using quickly. Many times I found myself digging into source code for finding useful methods, approaches, etc.

Today PnP is a broad terminology describing different things and including different github repositories.
For example there is PnP Sites Core component, containing different methods and patterns for SharePoint, there is also pnp-js-core - javascript component to work with SharePoint REST API, there is also repository contains a lot of different samples and technics around common SharePoint tasks.

It depends on your task, which module to use. If you are building some javascript parts, take a look at the [PnP-JS-Core](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core).
For .NET use [PnP-Sites-Core](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Sites-Core).

[PnP-PowerShell](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-PowerShell) for different PS tasks.

And finally [PnP](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP) if you are looking for samples, ready-to-use components or solutions.

For start, I can advise you to follow [Office Dev PnP Core Component–Training Package](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vesku/2016/04/12/office-dev-pnp-core-componenttraining-package/).
In the end you will have better understanding around topics covered by PnP and when to use it.

Answer (score 2):

[PnP-Sites-Core](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Sites-Core) - If you are using CSOM(.NET) based solutions in your project, then this provides extensions to the OOTB CSOM dlls. This fills many gaps that exist in the OOTB dlls and increases overall developer productivity.

For example, the OOTB CSOM doesnt have the `CreateContentType` method, once you add the PnP dll, this extension method is exposed.

***Language used - C#***

[PnP-JS-Core](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core) - If you javascript + REST extensively in your project, then you should add this js file reference to your project. Similar to the above `sites-core`, this also provides lots of flexibility to developers. Allows you to focus more on business logic and less on syntax. 
You simply need to add jquery and the pnp js core reference in a script editor webpart and you can start using it for RESTful operations.

***Language used - typescript,javascript***

[PnP-PowerShell](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell) - If your project uses powershell extensively, then you should install the executable. You can perform complex provisioning tasks and code management through this. Provides lots of extensions to the existing powershell commands and works quite well with CSOM. You can use the CSOM code in the powershell script to perform your tasks. 
For this, you need to just install the executable and then these powershell extension commands will be available for project use.

***Language used - C#,powershell***

[PnP-Provisioning-Schema](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Provisioning-Schema) - Used to remotely provision sites primarily in Office 365 using XML templates. You can create an XML template and based on that you can provision sites. For example, in the XML template, you can specify the features, pages, page layouts and webparts etc and based on this XML you quickly provision sites.

***Language used - C#,XML***

[PnP Samples](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP) - Provides production ready code as well as guidance and best practice for many business scenarios. Useful for any project created in Office 365/SharePoint 2013 and 2016 environments.

***Language used - C#,ASP.NET etc.***